# How to get around blank values in a cell when using an automatic script containing .getValue()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Scripts to run an automatic script to take data in a spreadsheet and replace the text in a document template for reporting reasons.

My problem is that when I run my code and obtain data from my sheet using this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1') ;
var P11 = sheet.getRange(79,7,1,1).getValue();
```

. . . and then try to place the data in the target document using this:

```
DocumentApp.openById('exampleId').getBody().replaceText('<<P11>>', P11);
```

it fails if the cell which I am getting the value from is blank.

Unfortunately the cells must remain blank.
Is there a way to make the script run without failing and just call a generic value in GAS much like how the =IFERROR() formula in sheets works?

*NOTE - I have around 150 .replaceText items for each run of the code.

Comment: `try{ //code }catch(e){ //iferror code }` ?. Why don't simply check if it is null or `""` ?

Comment: I still need to generate the report for the entries with null  data. I did in fact end up using an if statement on another column of the row in question which more than doubled the code but work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for empty string:

```
var P11 = sheet.getRange(79,7,1,1).getValue();
//Logger.log('P11: ' + P11);

if (P11 === "") {
  return;
};
```

Comment: I did end up using an if statement to solve this by checking the value of another column I had available and applying a different set of .replaceText options. Seemed only slighlty less coding than checking each item as you placed above. It does work though and fueled my success on this one so an answer vote either way.